# Python json decode and search

Tags: python, json

I have a python script which gets a JSON file from a URL saves it to a variable called `myjson`. The next step I am looking to proceed through the data and select individual fields and output those fields to a file.

The following is an example of the json file i get

```
{
"data":
    {"111111111":
        {
        "date":"Wed Feb 12 17:36:01 UTC 2014",
        "left":null,
        "right":"test",
        "category":"test",
        "owner":"test",
        "name":"test",
        "id":123456789123,
        "status":"test",
        "severity":"test",
        "subject":"test",
        },
    "111111112":
        {
        "date":"Wed Feb 12 17:36:01 UTC 2014",
        "left":null,
        "right":"test",
        "category":"test",
        "owner":"test",
        "name":"test",
        "id":123456789123,
        "status":"test",
        "severity":"test",
        "subject":"test",
        }

}
```

Ideally I would like to create a file with the "111111111" field and the content of the "subject":"test" (only the test returned) for each entry in the json data structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decode the JSON with the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), then just loop over the keys and values of the `data` dictionary; that's:

```
import json


json_data = json.loads(myjson)

for key, entry in json_data['data'].iteritems():
    print key, entry['subject']
```

If you are using Python 3, use `myjson['data'].items():` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am getting the following error now "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str" any advice?

Comment: just used json.loads(buf.getvalue()) before to decode the json data, and it worked! It's my second time ever using python. Trying to convert from PHP to Python. Thank you very much for your help, it is much appreciated